# Good citizen badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

Not certain if the site can do this, but I think it could help keep things lively if it could.

Could we set up a "Good Citizen" badge awarded when one has answered more questions than they have asked.

Even better if it could operate dynamically -- too many questions without answer contributions and the badge could fade or go away.

Personally I'd have some work to do if they instituted this on the other SE sites I occasionally visit, but here on my favorite one this would help keep me focused on contributing, which in the long run I find helps me learn even more about Mathematica because I need to provide clear and referenced solutions.

Comment: But why would we need it?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries -- If one looks at the most expert users on the site (you among them), they may have tens of questions, but have provided hundreds of answers.  That ratio of questions to answers captures a kind of participation in the community that reputation alone does not necessarily capture.  It goes to the generosity of spirit that they bring to the site.  A good citizen badge would just recognize that in the way other badges recognize different measures of participation.  A celebration of virtue.  Not bragging rights, just recognizing & appreciating a different order of contribution.

Comment: I can't quite see why this is supposed to be badge-worthy behavior either.

Comment: @J.M. Not to belabor a losing proposition, happy to withdrawal the question if it sees a couple more down boats.  Still I'll take one more shot to defend the idea.  An extreme example - 2 participants ea. with 2000 reputation points.  1 answered 100 questions and asked 1, the other answered 1 and asked 100.  I think the one who has answered 100 questions has made a qualitatively different kind of contribution to the site than the other.  All badges recognize different measures of participation.  It just doesn't seem that what I've just described gets directly acknowledged.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: A well thought out question can IMO be just as valuable as a good answer. In my experience lazy questions don't get more than like three votes whereas really good ones get way over 10. So, normally 100 just-so questions won't get you more than 300 rep. You just don't get 2000 rep for 100 bad questions.

Comment: Jagra, I'm afraid I have to add myself to the list of people who don't support this.  Nevertheless, you do not need to *withdraw* your question unless you are somehow embarrassed by it.  It will serve as a reference for the same or similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 7):

I think the fact that one gets 10 points for an upvote on an answer but only 5 for a question already sets up this incentive.

In any case, the way that so many of us [pile onto easier questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7977/8) makes it pretty obvious that there is an appetite for *more* questions, especially those that are good while not too hard, or that provide "teachable moments" for beginners that might visit the site in future.

Answer (score 4):

Though I understand why answering more questions than asking them could be a badge, there are two objections against this:

1. This must be an SO-wise decision, and that means a lot of inertia to overcome
2. Asking **good** questions in my opinion is sometimes as hard and demanding as answering questions. Furthermore, a good question can generate more traffic, reputation and knowledge than a good answer.

Of course point 2 is my main point. On the other hand, one can argue that there is a diverse set of badges rewarding various different strategies. What Jagra suggests is **as "badge-worthy behaviour"** as any, or at least many other badge-awarding behaviour on SO. Just think of **Autobiographer**: "Completed all user profile fields. Why is it badge-worthy? Now of course it is possible to justify it, but then it is equally easy to justify the badge proposed by Jagra. I personally wouldn't mind such a badge as I worked hard to develop an equal Q/A ratio, because for some reason (I never really gave it a full thought) I think it is the best for me and for the site.

Now of course if each persion was doing this that would result in an overall Q/A ratio of 1, which is not something that is appreciated on SO. And maybe this is my third, game theoretical objection.

Comment: +1 for the thoughtful and clear reply.  I very much agree that good questions can prove every bit as important as good answers.  I just began thinking about my Q/A ratio, because I've come to value this site so much that I want to do what I can to support its success, over the long run that seems better for both me and the site.